How can I write a templated C++23 class, which provide operator implementations for its derivatives?
I would like to have a (templated) base class, which, beyond common properties, already implements the operators for the derived classes.
The code I had is:
#include <concepts>
#include <optional>

template <class CLAZZ>
    requires(std::derived_from<CLAZZ, MyBaseClass<CLAZZ>>)
class MyBaseClass
{
    // Has some base properties
public:
    bool operator==(const CLAZZ other) const
    {
        return true; // For sure this is more complex
    }

    bool operator==(const std::optional<const CLAZZ> other) const
    {
        return true; // For sure this is more complex
    }
};

class MyDerivatedClass : public MyBaseClass<MyDerivatedClass>
{
    // More properties added
};

Thinking twice about it, it was clear that this cannot work, because the operators would need types, which does not exist so far.
Because of that, I use just the current class, instead of the final class, despite this brings the risk that accidentally two derived classes exist, which should not have a compatible comparison (safety precaution, would not really become a problem for my use-case I guess).
#include <concepts>
#include <optional>

template <class CLAZZ>
    requires(std::derived_from<CLAZZ, MyBaseClass<CLAZZ>>)
class MyBaseClass
{
    // Has some base properties
public:
    bool operator==(const MyBaseClass<CLAZZ> other) const
    {
        return true; // For sure this is more complex
    }

    bool operator==(const std::optional<const MyBaseClass<CLAZZ>> other) const
    {
        return true; // For sure this is more complex
    }
};

Unfortunately even then I get an error in requires clause, that MyBaseClass is not defined so far.
I then tried with a forward definition, which tells me that the requires clause is incompatible:
template <class CLAZZ>
class MyBaseClass;

Any suggestions how I could implement this and ensure that the operators only work with the derived class itself or at least only for the derivatives of this base class with a matching template argument?

If you derive a CLAZZ from MyBaseClass<class CLAZZ> it works to a degree - it's called CRTP. If you need some definitions or types from derived class, that's a  little harder to implement: you need a third class, which would be also a template, specialized for CLAZZ and being a base. Thing is, it can be specialized  separately at later time. Also, look up "deduced this" use for CRTP

deducing this example on builders, around 17m mark

@Swift-FridayPie @halyek Thanks for the hint, sounds interesting.
Unfortunately it seems I cannot mark functions using an explicit this argument as const any more, which is not great for operators.
Why is that/ is there a workaround?

@TorstenKnodt they should be differerent? type of deduced this includes const-ness, so that can be used

Alter your example to use deduced this:
class MyBaseClass
{
public:
    template <typename Self>
    constexpr bool operator==(this const Self& self, const Self& other)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass { };

static_assert(MyDerivedClass() == MyDerivedClass());

Because both arguments to operator== are of the same derived type, it cannot compare unrelated derived classes.
